# Bookmarklet for enabling the Chromevox extension

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension, bookmarklet, ubuntu-20.04

The Chromevox extension hijacks my letter "a" so that it activates and deactivates my enabled Chromevox extension.  That means if I'm typing something, everytime I hit the letter "a" Chromevox does something.  So I need to disable the Chromevox extension when I'm not using it.  Opening the extension maanager for this is a pain.  I'd like to have a custom keyboard shortcut or bookmarklet to toggle Chromevox enabled or disabled.  I think the javascript

`chrome.management.setEnabled(string id, boolean enabled, function callback)`

should do it, but I don't know how to find the string.  Any ideas?  I'm running Pop!_OS 20.04 which is more or less Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

As so often happens, I figure out a solution right after posting.  If you turn the extension on, from within the extension manager page, there is a hamburger menu.  Press that and choose keyboard shortcuts.  There are a number of shortcuts for Chromevox.  The last on is toggle Chromevox classic.  Change "In Chrome" to "Global."  When you hit the shortcut, it changes the Chromevox key; so that now you can type without problems.  When you are done typing, use the same shortcut to go back.